# How to call the header for href

Tags: php, string, href

this is the header that show when i login

```
"system/index.php?id=2"
```

I want to call the link in the header so i can edit the textarea, 
what code should I add in my code..

```
echo "$row[Describes] < a href = 'index.php?edit=$row[No]' > edit < /a >
```

Comment: Please describe your problem more accurate.

Comment: `header("Location: system/index.php?id=2")` Is that what you want

Comment: @RabNawaz no, i want here is when i click the edit it will go to the system/index.php?id=2 but my code only go to the index.php.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo $row['Describes'].' <a href="system/index.php?edit='.$row['No'].'>Edit</a>';
```